# why i Can't render the message notification although broadcast received for message

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here , i received message but the data is null although i have set up the data

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(26011): broadcast received for message
I/flutter (26011): Got a message whilst in the foreground!
I/flutter (26011): Message data: {}
I/flutter (26011): Message also contained a notification: Instance of 'RemoteNotification'
```

Here is my code

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  
NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);
print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
  // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

[here is my Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGgsN.png)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWjtP.png
[It don't display the notification, the simulator][1]

Comment: I have tried this few days back. Notification is delayed a lot these days, but you should have get the data in console. Can you try printing this `message.notification.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment section, firebase notifications are little bit delayed (experienced not mentioned anywhere) So you may not able to see it. But it will pop in a few minutes (again in my case).

One more reason you didn't get notification, as mentioned in [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage)

> Messages may have a RemoteMessage.Notification instance if they are
> received while the application is in the foreground, otherwise they
> will be automatically posted to the notification tray.

You are printing the `RemoteMessage.data` but you are sending notification from firebase console. `RemoteMessage` have a nested class `RemoteMessage.RemoteNotification`. You should have use this class to print the data sent from firebase console like this

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Notification Title: ${message.notification.title}');
    print('Notification Body: ${message.notification.body}');
  }
});
```

You can still use many properties from `RemoteNotification` as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification)